# Understanting Django inheritance templates

Tags: python, django

Im really lost about this, im trying to understand a django inheritance template about

I have a layout with a navbar and html structure:
todos/templates/todos/layout.html

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <title>Practice Django</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark justify-content-between">
      <div>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Django app</a>
        <a href="#" class="navbar-item mr-3">Page 1</a>
        <a href="#" class="navbar-item">Page 2</a>
      </div>
      <form action="" class="form-inline">
        <input
          type="search"
          placeholder="Search Todo"
          aria-label="Search"
          class="form-control mr-sm-2"
        />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0">
          Search
        </button>
      </form>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        {% block content %} {% endblock %}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

then im trying to setup a index page with a grid, a column for show todos and the another one for create a new todo.

todos/templates/todos/base.html

```
{% block content %}
<h1 class="text-center">Base Page</h1>
<div class="row">
    
    <div class="col">
        {% block todolist %} 
            {% include 'todos/todos_list.html' %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        {% block addtodo %} 
            {% include 'todos/add_todo.html' %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

todos/templates/todos/add_todo.html

```
{% extends 'todos/base.html' %}
{% block addtodo %} 
    <h3 class="text-center">subpage addtodo</h3>
{% endblock %}
```

todos/templates/todos/todos_list.html

```
{% extends 'todos/base.html' %}
{% block todolist %} 
    <h3 class="text-center">subpage todolist</h3>
{% endblock %}
```

For try to understand it, i made a same classes for both views, todo_list and add_todo from different class sources.
views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect, Http404
from django.template import loader
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView

from .models import Todo

class TodoList(ListView):
    template_name = 'todos/todos_list.html'
    context_object_name= 'todos'

    # Lo que devuelve esta funcion se añade al context object name
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Todo.objects.all()

class AddTodo(ListView):
    template_name = 'todos/add_todo.html'
    context_object_name= 'todos'

    # Lo que devuelve esta funcion se añade al context object name
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Todo.objects.all()
```

My urls.py i guess, to show both classes in index pages, the same route url

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.TodoList.as_view(), name='todolist'),
    path('', views.AddTodo.as_view(), name='addtodo')
]
```

But this does not work, with this error:

**RecursionError at /
maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version:     3.1.1
Exception Type:     RecursionError
Exception Value:

maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
Exception Location:     /home/adrian/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py, line 241, in inner
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
Python Version:     3.8.2
Python Path:

['/home/adrian/code/python/practice',
'/usr/lib/python38.zip',
'/usr/lib/python3.8',
'/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
'/home/adrian/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages',
'/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages',
'/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 24 Sep 2020 16:43:24 +0000**

I was thinking to make both operations (show todo list and add a new todo form) with the same class, but i dont know how do it that properly, the object its show a both classes, templates in the same route, in this case in root /.

Any clues about? thanks in advance

Comment: You should not use `{% include %}`, since then you end up with infinite recursion.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use `{% include %}`, since then you end up with infinite recursion. You can for example make a base:

```
{% block content %}
<h1 class="text-center">Base Page</h1>
<div class="row">
    
    <div class="col">
        {% block items %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        {% block otheritems %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

If you later use [**`{% extend … %}`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#extends), it means you take the entire template of the one your refer to, but for the blocks you specify and the "*child* template", you render another value. So your child can look for example as:

```
{% extends 'todos/base.html' %}
{% block items %} 
    <h3 class="text-center">subpage addtodo</h3>
{% endblock %}
```

```
{% extends 'todos/base.html' %}
{% block items %} 
    <h3 class="text-center">subpage todolist</h3>
{% endblock %}
```

Here you will thus render the `<h1 class="">` part in the child templates. The only thing that will differ is that the part in the block `{% block items %} … {% endblock %}` by the content you provide.

Here it however looks like you want *two* views to provide content for the same page. That is *not* how it works. A view is the logic that maps a request to a response. A view does not per se renders a template, nor does it only renders maximum one template. A view can render as much templates as you want.

If you thus want a single page with two items to fill in, you make a view, that renders for example a template that fills in the two blocks. So we thus define a single URL pattern for this path:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.TodoList.as_view(), name='add_todo'),
]
```

and in the view, we allow one to also access the list of todos:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect, Http404
from django.template import loader
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView

from .models import Todo

class TodoList(CreateVieww):
    template_name = 'todos/todos_list.html'
    model = Todo
    fields = '__all__'

    def todos(self):
        return Todo.objects.all()
```

in the template, we finally fill in two blocks: one with the `Todo`s, and one with the form:

```
{% extends 'todos/base.html' %}
{% block items %} 
    {% for todo in view.todos %}
        {{ todo }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}

{% block otheritems %}
    <form method="post" action="{% url 'add_todo' %}">
        {{ form }}
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```